# How to create complex shape in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2

I remember in java 2D i could create area from my shape and add other shapes to it or subtract.

is it possible to do the same in javafx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be after the [`Polygon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/Polygon.html) class which lets you define complex polygons by passing an array of points into the constructor. As for "adding other shapes to it or subtracting", I presume you mean intersecting / subtracting with other shapes - in which case have a look at Shape.subtract(), [`Shape.intersect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#intersect%28javafx.scene.shape.Shape,%20javafx.scene.shape.Shape%29), and Shape.union(). All are static methods on the `Shape` class which take two shapes as a parameter and return the result.

Comment: tanx @berry120, but polygon does not fit to my need. i will use `Shape.union(shape,shape)`